# My python code exception "list index out of range"

Tags: python

I want to print like list by python:

```
#          1
#        1   1
#      1   2   1
#    1   3   3   1
#  1   4   6   4   1
#1   5   10  10  5   1
```

It is YangHui triangle, and expect print is:

```
# [1]
# [1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1]
# [1, 3, 3, 1]
# [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
# [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
# [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
# [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
# [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
# [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
....
```

But an exception appear:

> IndexError: list index out of range

[image]

It tells me that at line 28. I check it time after time, but I don't know why. Who can answer me?

This is python code:

```
def triangles():

    row = 1

    while True:

        triangle = [[1],[1,1]]
        if row == 1:
            print(triangle[row - 1])

        if row == 2:
            print(triangle[row - 1])

        if row > 2:
            #init the n list
            subn = [1]*row
            for i in range(row):

                #if subn[1] ~ subn[row -2]
                if i > 0 and i < (row - 1):
                    a = triangle[row - 2][i]
                    b = triangle[row - 2][i - 1]
                    subn[i] = a + b
            triangle.append(subn)
            print(triangle[row - 1])
        row = row + 1

triangles()
```

Comment: This is Pascal's triangle. Who renamed it?

Comment: Exception tracebacks are *text*, please don't use a screenshot for that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: that's just the name we give to the triangle *in the west*, but the technique predates Pascal. Yang Hui is a valid name, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Hui (who wrote about the triangle a mere 400 years earlier).

Comment: Also, `i` ranges up to `row`, but the preceding row is *shorter*. `triangle[row - 2]` is going to be *two elements shorter*. So why would you expect `triangle[row - 2][row]` or `triangle[row - 2][row - 1]` to exist?

Comment: @BiaoQiu: [edit] your question, don't put that in a comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wait  a minute ,this is my first time to ask question by stackoverflow

Comment: @MartijnPieters `if row == 3`,it can print `[1, 2, 1]`,why don't print `[1, 3, 3, 1]` when row == 4?

Comment: @MartijnPieters his row numbering is strange, but actually does 'work' (not saying I wouldn't re-write the whole thing if this was my code). The reason the code is throwing an error is because he is re-assigning `triangle` each time.

Comment: @Stael: nice catch; indeed, the `i` value is further constrained with an `if` statement that I missed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think given the difficulty in debugging the code you can make a case that it is wrong just because of how unclear it is! It looks like a learning exercise though, so I wish the OP luck - I'm sure I wrote worse when I was first doing python.

Comment: @Stael: I can show you some LPC and MSX BASIC code that'll make you cringe.

Comment: @Stael Thanks for your answer!This is my first time coding by python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your help,bro

Comment: @BiaoQiu you're welcome. As someone with more experience in python, i would suggest using numeric indexing as little as possible - it is confusing and goes wrong easily. One of the advantages of python is that you don't need to do this, you could instead use tools like enumerate and list comprehensions, which are confusing at first but very powerful when you get used to them. Solid first attempt though, I've done much worse!

Comment: @Stael This is sounds great for a python beginner.Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, the problem is that you are assigning `triangle` within your loop.

every time you create and assign a new row you append it to the variable `triangle`, but then you loop around again and reassign it to `[[1],[1,1]]` which loses the appended row. You think you have more rows than you do, hence index out of range.

```
def triangles():

    row = 1

    while True:

        triangle = [[1],[1,1]]
        if row == 1:
            print(triangle[row - 1])
```

should be:

```
def triangles():

    row = 1
    triangle = [[1],[1,1]]
    while True:


        if row == 1:
            print(triangle[row - 1])
```

also, you should limit this in some way otherwise it is a perpetual loop.

put

```
if row > 100:
    break
```

in the `while` loop